# select basing on count

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table Bill.

This table have a field `Id_Client`.

I want to recover a list with the Clients that exceed a number  of bills.

In SQL, I do something like this

```
select Id_Client, Count(*)
from MyDB.dbo.Bill
group by Id_Client
having Count(*) > 100
order by c desc
```

Where 100, is a example of this limit.

I want to do this in Entity Framework - LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query= db.Bills.GroupBy(b => b.Id_Client)
                   .Select(g => new {Id_Client = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
                   .Where(r => r.Count > 100)
                   .OrderByDescending(r=>r.Count);
```

This Linq query will be translated to this query in sql:

```
{SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Id_Client], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id_Client] AS [K1], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Bill] AS [Extent1]
    GROUP BY [Extent1].[Id_Client]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
WHERE [GroupBy1].[A1] > 100
ORDER BY [GroupBy1].[A1] DESC}
```